# Flutter packages offline development with "any"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, offline

Developing in an air gapped environment. All package dependencies have to be cloned or downloaded separately and then manually transferred to development area.

This works in pubspec.yaml for most packages so far.

For Example:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

# Animated, highly customizable, open-source Flutter gauge indicator widget. 
# MIT licence
  gauge_indicator: 
    path: C:/DevTools/gauge_indicator
    version: ^0.4.3

dependency_overrides:
#Equatable overrides == and hashCode for you so you don't have to 
#waste your time writing lots of boilerplate code.
#MIT licence
  equatable: 
    path: C:/DevTools/equatable
    version: ^2.0.5
```

Problem with "any"

However, when the package includes other dependencies, as in the case of "provider", the option above does not work if the version is described as "any"

```
#A wrapper around InheritedWidget to make them easier to use and more reusable.
#MIT licence 
  provider:
    path: C:/DevTools/provider/packages/provider
    version: ^6.1.2
```

Error:

```
[hello_flutter] flutter pub get --offline --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
Because every version of provider from path depends on nested any which doesn't exist (could not find package nested in cache), provider from path is forbidden.
So, because hello_flutter depends on provider from path, version solving failed.
```